# UITabBarController throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I create a tab bar controller in the app delegate. Here is the .h and .m file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface appAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
UIWindow *window;
UITabBarController *tabBar;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITabBarController *tabBar;

@end
```

here is the relevant function in the m file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

UINavigationController *localNav;

tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *controllerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];

FirstViewController  *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
localNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:FirstViewController];
localNav.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

[controllerArray addObject:localNav];

[firstViewController release];

SecondViewController *secondViewController;
secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
localNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];
[controllerArray addObject:localNav];
[localNav release];
[SecondViewController release];

tabBar.viewControllers = controllerArray;

[controllerArray release];
[localNav release];

[window addSubview:tabBar.view];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

I changed the variable names (ie the first view is not called first view controller). The app will load and show two tabs that I can choose between. The issue comes in when I try to show a modal popup. I have a button that when pressed should show the modal.

Here is the .h file. The custom button just rounds the corners of the button, other than that it is a straight extension of UIButton. The delegate just has functions for two buttons that are ok or cancel.:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomButton.h"
#import "StartModal.h"
#import "CurrentEntry.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <StartModalDelegate>{
CustomButton *startEntry;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet CustomButton *startEntry;

 - (IBAction) startLogEntry;
 - (void) locationSelection;

- (void) dismissHandler;
- (void) saveHandler;
```

@end

The EXC_BAD_ACCESS comes in when I run the function for the button press. Here is the .m file:

```
- (IBAction) startLogEntry {
NSLog(@"start the entry here");

StartPoopModal *modal = [[StartModal alloc] initWithNibName:@"StartModal" bundle:nil];
[modal setDelegate:self];

UINavigationController *localNav;
localNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:modal];
localNav.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:localNav animated:YES];
[modal release];
}
```

the [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController....] is what throws the error. This has worked in the past and for some reason it is throwing an error. As far as I know I haven't changed it. I don't have this in any form of version control so I cannot double check it.

Comment: I figured it out. Patrick brings up good points about the release. I had made one view controller and then copied/pasted it into the wrong spot and I didn't look over it completely. The other point about the type being wrong was not an issue as I didn't update the name correctly in the question. I was making an application for shits and giggles to figure out all the different ways to use views (tabs, nav bars, and modals) and had named it StartPoopModal, but I didn't want to use that in the question. Anyways back to what the issue was, it was a subview of the modal (again just trying stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the line

```
[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:localNav animated:YES];
```

causes a bad access exception (EXC_BAD_ACCESS), then you should be looking for bad pointers. I see four pointers involved there: `self`, `self.tabBarController`, `localNav`, and `modal`.

I agree with @PatrickAnarna that the line where you allocate `modal` is suspicious because the types don't match, but if `StartModal` is a real class then that shouldn't cause the bad access exception. However, if `modal` is nil, then you'd expect a bad access exception when the tab bar controller tries to access `modal`'s view. Or more specifically, when the tab bar controller tries to access `localNav`'s view, and `localNav` in turn tries to access `modal`'s view.

I don't see how `localNav` would be nil or invalid, but you should still check that. `self` should never be nil in an instance method, and if `self` is a view controller that's managed by a tab bar controllers, `self.tabBarController` shouldn't be nil or invalid either. Again, though, you shouldn't assume that they're correct just because they're supposed to be -- after all the code is supposed to work, but it doesn't.

Anyway, at the end of the day, the error is caused by dereferencing a bad pointer. Find the pointer that's being dereferenced and you'll find your error.

Comment: I found the issuing being a subview of the modal. The modal wasn't nil, but it didn't throw an error until I tried to use it.

Comment: I chose you as the answer as although Patrick did bring up a good point about memory management (we all can be more careful about that) it was not the solution to the problem and your answer was more helpful to the issue at hand. It seems like, in the iPhone categories at least, if you make a mistake about memory management it gets voted up instead of the actual issue. Although it was a leak it was not where the error was thrown and should have been a comment or an aside, like yours :)

Answer (score 2):

First you did this.

```
localNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:FirstViewController];
[controllerArray addObject:localNav];
```

then you did this. that's a leak right there. you didn't release local nav before giving it a new OWNED object.

```
localNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];
[controllerArray addObject:localNav];
```

after that you did this

```
[localNav release];
```

then after awhile again, you called [localNav release] again.

and also, this line is suspicious

```
 StartPoopModal *modal = [[StartModal alloc] initWithNibName:@"StartModal" bundle:nil];
```

you assigned two different classes

all i can say is check all the above bad programming and make sure to read memory management rules.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

really helpful.

Comment: I am used to managed languages and sometimes memory management throws me off. From a conceptual standpoint it seems easy, but in practice...